# Cordova BluetoothLE Detects only mac laptop no other devices?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, bluetooth, ionic-framework

I was trying to figure out how BLE works. Tried to go through one of the [cordova plugin](https://github.com/randdusing/ng-cordova-bluetoothle) using ionic framework. Have followed all the steps mentioned in document:

[image]

Build for android everything is working great.

But whenever i used to startScan it only detects my Mac even if my all other devices are enabled, I wanna know:

> How the app scan for all the bluetooth devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is detecting your Mac, it sounds like things are working.

In order for a Bluetooth Low Energy scan to find other devices, those devices need to be advertising Bluetooth Low Energy services.

If you don't have any Bluetooth LE peripherals, you can use [LightBlue](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue-explorer-bluetooth/id557428110?mt=8) to create virtual peripherals on iOS devices or [nRF Master Control Panel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=en) to create virtual peripherals on newer Android devices.

[bleno](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/bleno) can be used to create Bluetooth Low Energy peripherals with Node.js on OS X, Linux and Windows.

Comment: Used LightBlue and created virtual peripherals it resolved my issue thanks :)